# setOnChildClickListener of expandablelistview doesn't take action

Tags: android, eclipse, expandablelistview

I am newbie to android development .

My goal to make  an Expandable List view  and on each child of a group of that expandable

list view I want to set an event when that child clicked.

So  I have downloaded  a ready android project from here .

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/06/hiding-group-indicator-for-empty-groups.html

and run it by eclipse IDE .

[image]

I add this code to ExpList3 class to test an event.

but no  event gained when press any   child of a list view group

```
getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                    if(groupPosition==0&&childPosition==0 )
                    {
                        TextView myTextView = 
                                 (TextView)findViewById(R.id.groupname);
                                 myTextView.setText("Text Changed");
                    }

                    else if(groupPosition==0&&childPosition==1)
                    {
                        TextView myTextView = 
                                 (TextView)findViewById(R.id.groupname);
                                  myTextView.setText("Text Changed");
                    }   
                    else if(groupPosition==1&&childPosition==0&&id==0)
                    {
                        TextView myTextView = 
                                 (TextView)findViewById(R.id.groupname);
                                 myTextView.setText("Text clicked");    

                    } 
                    return false;

                }

            });
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: @PiyushGupta No event gained when press any child of a list view group

Comment: Must check this returns true isChildSelectable.

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun make sure your `isChildSelectable()` returns `true` in your `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and from your code, it will only work for Grey group and its first two child.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh isChildSelectable returns true in my code.

Comment: @PiyushGupta isChildSelectable returns true in my code.

Comment: Have you got any error??

Comment: I have not get any error but I get those warnings:                        [2014-03-10 12:05:41 - ExpList3] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2014-03-10 12:05:41 - ExpList3] Device API version is 17 (Android 4.2)

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun you trying to change the text of your group `TextView`? use a `Toast` in your listener and see if you getting a toast or not.

Comment: I used the following statements between if as well as between else if but didn't got a toast .                                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
 CharSequence text = "Hello toast 0";
 int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
 toast.show();

Answer (score 0):

You have used a textview and setting clicked list item in the textview. Use Toast to view the clicked item. Also location of the textview matters in displaying your clicked item.

Comment: I used the following statements between if as well as between else if but didn't got a toast . Context context = getApplicationContext(); CharSequence text = "Hello toast 0"; int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT; Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration); toast.show();